# how to vertically align the 'email promo' text in the top nav bar next to the img as well as the other text links?

Tags: html, css

Ive been trying to learn CSS and HTML and am struggling with a few things. i can seem to get my head around how to position elements on the page with CSS? i need to vertically align the elements inside the top nav bar but can't seem to figure it out for the life of me. Im not just looking for a simple answer i would like a explanation of what i have done incorrectly that prevents me from being able to move elements to where i need them to be :) 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
here is the code and js fiddle link 
https://jsfiddle.net/9trux138/2/

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.topbar {
  background-color: #17D8C7;
  height: 35px;
  overflow: hidden;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 2% 0 2%;
}

.topbar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.topbar ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.topbar ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.topbar ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.topbar ul li img {
  height: 24px;
  padding: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
}

.topright li {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-gb">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
  <title>Complete Suites</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body class="body">
  <header class="topbar">
    <ul class="topleft">
      <li>
        <a href="#"><img src="https://s8.postimg.cc/6t7njymhx/location-pin.png
" alt="Location Pin"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#"><img src="https://s8.postimg.cc/ytbr47v39/contact-email.png" alt="Contact Email"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#"><img src="https://s8.postimg.cc/fbh3oalat/open-time.png
" alt="Opening Times"></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="topmiddle">
      <li>
        <a href="#"><img src="https://s8.postimg.cc/ytbr47v39/contact-email.png" alt="Email Promotions Sign Up"><span>Email Promotions</span></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="topright">
      <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </header>


</body>

</html>
```

James

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove padding-top from the img tags it will prevent the default centering when we use `vertical-align: middle;.`

Also you need to add `vertical-align: middle` on the span and img tags inside the anchor, instead of the anchor.

```
.topbar ul li a span {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.topbar ul li img {
  height: 24px;
  padding: 0 5px 0px 0px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.topbar {
  background-color: #17D8C7;
  height: 35px;
  overflow: hidden;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 2% 0 2%;
}

.topbar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.topbar ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.topbar ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.topbar ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.topbar ul li a span {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.topbar ul li img {
  height: 24px;
  padding: 0 5px 0px 0px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-gb">

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    <title>Complete Suites</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  </head>

  <body class="body">
    <header class="topbar">
      <ul class="topleft">
        <li><a href="#"><img src="https://s8.postimg.cc/6t7njymhx/location-pin.png
" alt="Location Pin"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="https://s8.postimg.cc/ytbr47v39/contact-email.png" alt="Contact Email"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="https://s8.postimg.cc/fbh3oalat/open-time.png
" alt="Opening Times"></a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="topmiddle">
        <li><a href="#"><img src="https://s8.postimg.cc/ytbr47v39/contact-email.png" alt="Email Promotions Sign Up"><span>Email Promotions</span></a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="topright">
        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </header>


  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The other text links - Blog, About Us, and Contact -  appear to be vertically centered.

Your issue with Email Promotions is the way you're embedding a `span` tag within the same `li` tag that also contains an `img` tag.
As another poster answered, you can additional css to explicitly align this `span` vertically, if you so choose.

However, why not make it two `li` tags - one for the image and one for the text?

ie.

```
<li><a href="#"><img src="https://s8.postimg.cc/ytbr47v39/contact-email.png" alt="Email Promotions Sign Up"></a></li>
<li>Email Promotions</li>
```

Let me know if you're looking for more guidance.

Comment: brilliant thank you explained why it wasnt working perfectly :)

i have gone with the adjusting and additional css as i didn't want to have two separate links for the email promo element. 

my only question is do you have any advice on how to learn CSS and html more in depth? i have done the w3schools tutorials and exercises but i need somewhere that demonstrates in real world scenarios.